# Get user info via Google API for IP address

Tags: oauth, google-api, userinfo

Is it possible to get information from user's profile via Google API? If it is possible, which API should I use?

I'm interesting  in such information:

Url to the user profile 
Gender (sex);
Profile photo.
Ip address wherefrom he/she login

I am getting other user information but How we can get IP address of the current session using google API ?

Currently I am giving SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"

For getting userinfo I am using session.get('https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me').json()

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the [Google+ API](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/#api-calls). Just so you know, it’s being deprecated, with a full shutdown in March.

Comment: Can we use another API for getting IP address of user ?  I know Google+ API is getting shutdown in March